# How to keep button active after press with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen some very similar questions floating around but haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for. I've already determined a work-around but would like to know the proper way to perform the task.

What I desire is to click the button and have the active state stay persistent. The next click will toggle the state and that is desired. What I really need to know is how to address the uiButton:active state.

HTML:

```
<input type='button' class='uiButton' id='testbutton' value='testValue'>
```

CSS:

```
.uiButton{
    background-color: red;
}

.uiButton:active{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('.uiButton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass(//active state);
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should create an active class

***CSS***

```
.uiButton:active, .active {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

***JS***

```
$('.uiButton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: That's the workaround I currently have. I was trying to see if there is a better way.

Comment: You're correct. I was just hoping to have a more elegant solution. If there isn't one I'll stick with what I had! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`:active` is a css [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes). You want `.active` which is the [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) that's being added to the element.

Answer (score -1):

You want the button to keep the active class after it's clicked? (not sure if you want to allow to be untoggled (red) again?).. Anyways...

CSS:

```
.uiButton {
   background-color: red;
}

.uiButton-active, .uiButton:hover {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Then....:

```
$('.uiButton').unbind('click').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('class', 'uiButton-active');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't trigger a css pseudo selector like `:active`. The only option I know ist to simulate this

```
.uiButtonActive {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Check out the working [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VWtXZ/)